# Munkres Chapter 1, Section 7, Problem 7: How to see if these two sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the set of all the sequences of natural numbers, and let $B$ be the set of all the binary sequences (i.e. all sequences whose terms are either $0$ or $1$). How to determine---preferably using the Shroeder Bernstein Theorem---if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: Is the `binary sequence' infinite or finite (numbers of 1's)?

Comment: @Ma Ming, the set $A$ consists of all the functions $f \colon Z^+ \to Z^+$, whereas the set $B$ consists of all the functions $g \colon Z^+ \to \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any $x = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots\} \in A$

$$F(x) = \{\underbrace{1,1,1, \cdots}_{x_1}, 0, \underbrace{1,1,1,\cdots}_{x_2}, 0, \cdots\}$$ gives an injection from $A$ to $B$

And for any $y = \{y_1, y_2, \cdots\} \in B$

$$G(y) = y$$ gives an injection from $B$ to $A$

Comment: you $G(y) = y$ cannot give a map from $B$ into $A$ because the set $B$ consists of all the functions $g \colon Z^+ \to \{0,1\}$, whereas the set $A$ consists of all the functions $f \colon Z^+ \to Z^+$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud so $B$ is one part of $A$, so $G(y) = y$ is injective from $B$ to $A$. $G$ is not surjective but it is a map from $B$ to $A$, isn't it?

Comment: I think you wanna define $G$ as follows: $G(y)\colon= (1+y_1, 1+y_2, \ldots)$, where $y \colon= (y_1, y_2, \ldots)$. Am I right?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud It depends if we include $0$ in the natural numbers. For me, $0$ is a natural number, so...